# SBT prepare WAR file, duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I am trying to pack one of the modules of my application into a `war`.
I have chosen [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) to help me out.

I have prepared the sbt, I guess correctly:

```
lazy val `my-project` = (project in file("my-project"))
                         ...
                         .enablePlugins(TomcatPlugin)
```

But during `sbt package` I get this error:

```
[info] Packaging /home/siatkowskim/Documents/....target/scala-2.11/my-project_2.11-1.2-SNAPSHOT.war ...
[error] java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

I am familiar with `sbt-assembly` but I see no way of deduplication here.
How can I even debug, where is it duplicated from? Or how to solve this duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I had `MANIFEST.MF` file in my classpath. 
I do not know what it was for, but removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, yet I had no evident `MANIFEST.MF` file in my classpath. I can only suppose that it was coming from the multitude of `.jar` files included.

The following solved the problem:

```scala
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
  (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
    case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _ => MergeStrategy.last
  }
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849682/what-does-double-colon-or-colon-colon-mean-in-scala) to understand what the double colon notation means.