# What does double colon (or colon-colon) :: mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming, sbt, sbt-assembly

I was having an issue with the `sbt` build of my Scala project (*duplicate entry:* `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) and the following lines solved the problem:

```scala
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
      case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case _ => MergeStrategy.last
    }
}
```

I am now trying to understand what the double colon means in the above context. I found an answer in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-do-double-colons-mean-in-the-Scala-programming-language), but this did not help.

Moreover, I am a newbie to Scala which does not really help.

**Edit:**

Seeing the answers, I still don't understand why since we are creating a list the following does not work (duplicate `manifest.mf` entries are not discarded):

```scala
case List("manifest.mf", "index.list", "dependencies") => MergeStrategy.discard
```

But the following does:

```scala
case List("manifest.mf") | List("index.list") | List("dependencies") => MergeStrategy.discard
```

And for those interested into the topic... [5 ways to create lists in Scala](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-create-scala-list-range-fill-tabulate-constructors).

Comment: Because you are not creating a List of three elements _(also you had a extra parenthesis)_. It is comparing the input with three different lists using and or.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, `"manifest.mf" :: Nil` is the same with `List("manifest.mf"). 
It is just a way to make or pattern match a list.

There are good resources for how pattern matching (also search `unapply`) work in Scala, mainly used in `case` statements.

Here it says: If that list has one element, and that is one of (`manifest.mf`,`index.list`, `dependencies`) then pick `MergeStrategy.discard`

Comment: Adding a link for the offical documentation: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a name of a class (yes, `::` is a valid name of a class). It's resolved as `Nil.::(arg)` since every method, that's ending with colon is right associative, which in turn resolves to `::(arg, Nil)`. This constructs a list with given parameters (prepends the element to existing list or creates one if invoked on `Nil`).